# Android java Math.sin(Math.Pi) returns a value greater than 0 instead of 0

Tags: java, android

I am not an experienced coder. Recently, while I was doing some coding on Android, I found out that Math.sin(Math.Pi) gives a value greater than 0 instead of 0. Anyone knows why is that happening and what is the fix?

Thanks.

**Edited explanation:**

In case of sin(0) and sin(Pi), I was expecting 0 value and I programmed this way. So, this give an error because I was actually multiplying the returned value with some number. So instead of getting zero, I was having a bigger value.

Comment: would you please so kind to post the value that you got here?

Comment: it is impossible. Sin is defined between -1 and 1

Comment: It gives `1.2246467991473532E-16` in my system which is lesser than 1 and very near to 0. Print it as `(int)Math.sin(Math.PI)` , you will get 0.

Comment: What you are saying is simply not true, probably you should study how floating points are represented in scientific number notation (1.2246467991473532E-16 : this is nearly 0 not 1.2 !)

Comment: @TheNewIdiot casting `Math.sin` to an int will always give 0 or -1, so that isn't really helpful. However, it is true that `1.22...E-16` is very close to 0.

Comment: @Jave, I know that , Op needs to format the `double` value instead of using `int`. `int` was just a quick pointer from my side.

Comment: A sine curve goes off to infinity or at least the end of the blackboard.

Comment: @devnull Sine curve goes off to infinity ? Are you talking about tan ?

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Try to think `horizontally`.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot I'm surprised that you never read that in a fortune cookie.

Comment: What is the fix? `if( theta == Math.PI ) return 0; else return Math.sin(theta);`

Comment: @devnull Your point, if there is one, escapes me. The question is about the value, i.e. the *y* axis.

Comment: @johnchen902 Well that is what I did before even asking the question. I think this is something like making things willingly modified. This way I can even write 2 + 2 gives 5 isn't it? :) But can anyone explain why is the return value like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the javadoc states

> The computed result must be within 1 ulp of the exact result.

Part of the problem is you cannot exactly represent PI so you can't expect an exact result to much.  I suggest you round off the result if you believe this is an error.